# Check if my ViewStub is inflated/visible and is null/non null?

Tags: android, viewstub

I did see a bunch of other posts before asking this question. None seemed to have a definite solution.

I am running into a issue with ViewStub where I want to check if a ViewStub is inflated or not (visible or not). I have a bunch of other things to do based on that.

I am using two ViewStubs and a button in each ViewStub layout namely in layout/abc and layout/def will inflate the other ViewStub.

```
<ViewStub
 android:id="@+id/abc_stub"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout="@layout/abc" />

 <ViewStub
 android:id="@+id/def_stub"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout="@layout/def" />
```

The issue I am running into is that the ViewStub that is not inflated is not null while I expect it to be null.

Is there anything I am missing ?

Comment: OnInflateListener, isn't it what you want?

Comment: Actually not, I need to write a funtionality based on where one of the Viewstubs in inflated or both of them are inflated.

Comment: I dont see any reason why listeners could not do that....

Comment: My question is why does the other ViewStub which is not inflated not null in the first case.

Comment: If not inflated ViewStub were null what use would it be with such null object? How could you call inflate() method on that null object? Or maybe i am missing completely your point?

Comment: You are correct. What was I thinking. I solved the issue using OnInflateListener.  Thanks pskink :). You can write an answer for me to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was to setOnInflateListener (ViewStub.OnInflateListener inflateListener)

```
ViewStub stub1 = ((ViewStub)findViewById(KR.get(R.abc_stub)));
stub1.setOnInflateListener(new ViewStub.OnInflateListener{
     @Override
     public void onInflate(ViewStub paramViewStub, View paramView) {
       // Set a class boolean if it was inflated                             
     }
});
```

If the boolean is true stub1 is the screen that is up. Else its not.

Thanks to @pskink for the help.

Answer (score 9):

I would like to present an alternative solution that does not rely on a listener.

```
View stub = findViewById(R.id.my_view_stub);
if(stub instanceof ViewStub) {
   // it have not been inflated
} else {
   // if have been inflated
}
```

the logic behind that is that after inflation, the `ViewStub` gets removed from the view hierarchy and replaced by what was on the inflated layout.

That means `stub` will be an `instanceOf FrameLayout/LinearLayout/Button` or whatever other view was on the inflated layout and the actual `ViewStub` instance is gone and if you're not holding a reference to it, it might even have been garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

More elegant solution:

```
if (mViewStub.getParent() != null) { 
    //have not been inflated
    mViewStub.inflate();
} else { 
    //already inflated
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Incase somebody still confuse about this...

### 1. What does `ViewStub.inflate()` actual do?

```java
// checkout android.view.ViewStub#inflate
// ...
// Actual inflate the xml
final View view = inflateViewNoAdd(parent);
// removte the same id view in parent, then re-add in view just inflated.
replaceSelfWithView(view, parent);
// ...
```

### 2. How do we check if it inflated?

Like Budius' anwser, below is the kotlin version:

```kotlin
/**
 * Find ViewStub
 * 1. if not yet inflate, then inflate
 * 2. If it has been inflated, return it directly
 * 3. ViewStub itself does not force the value of inflateId, but if you use this method and you don't set the inflateId, it will set the id of the view to the id of ViewStub when it is inflated.
 * 4. If the layout you're inflated to has an id, then don't set the inflateId, as it will override your original id when you inflate
 */


inline fun <reified T : View> View?.findViewStubById(
    viewStubId: Int,
    inflateId: Int = viewStubId
): T? {
    if (this == null) {
        return null
    }
    val find = this.findViewById<T?>(viewStubId) ?: return findViewById(inflateId)
    return if (find is ViewStub) {
        val view = find.inflate() as T
        if (view.id == View.NO_ID) {
            view.id = inflateId
        }
        view
    } else {
        find
    }
}
```